# Python requests module post returning 200 but no data written

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python 3.7 with requests module 2.22.0

following is my code in python :

```
data = { "id": 35, "name": "sample", "user": 1, "account": 3, 
"auto_remove_resource": "N", "generations": 30, "enabled": True, 
"schedules": [1], "description": "" }

response = requests.post( url=url, json={"json_payload": data}, 
headers=headers, verify=False )

print(response.status_code)
```

It is returning 200 for get it performs but gives 301 for post request. same post works well with postman.

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool: "POST url HTTP/1.1" 301 0 
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:"GET url HTTP/1.1" 200 3718 200
```

I have given following headers

```
headers = { "Accept": "application/json;", "Content-Type": 
"application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(mytoken), }
```

any help would be appreciated ?

Comment: check server logs (and error handling there) for the same.

Comment: in postman there is a code button click it, and between options choose python -> Requests and  then compare output with you code .

Comment: Sukh, can you please share your postman collection, So I can review the request and help to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i got it fixed by using version 1.3 in header in "Accept"

Comment: now my Authorization code looks like this : headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json; version=1.3",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(mytoken),
} and this has solved the issue. I think it might be something to do with server side code compatibility. Thanks for quick replies